# How to force Onboard appear on top of fullscreen apps in a tablet running Ubuntu?

Tags: fullscreen, okular, window-management, onboard

Whenever Okular is fullscreen, there is no way to make Onboard remain on top of Okular.
This behavior makes it impossible to annotate a fullscreen document (opened in Okular) in a touch screen tablet without a keyboard. It is also hard to exit the fullscreen mode ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>f</kbd> ) in a tablet.

How to force onboard remain on top of fullscreen apps like Okular?

In this image, Okular is full screen, and the icon to open onboard is visible.
[image: First image]

The second image shows that as soon as I click/tap the icon to open onboard, it goes behind the fullscreen Okular window.

[image]

Now there is no way to either annotate a document, or get out of the fullscreen mode without a keyboard (e.g. in a tablet).

After closing Okular (with keyboard), Onboard is visible.
[image]

I am using Lubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: Have you tried a different display-keyboard?  Onboard is a GTK3 one, and yes I just tested on my *kinetic* system and I get exactly as you describe (though I used this `firefox` window instead of `okular`)...  I used to QA using tablet but the Lubuntu team decided it was *wishlist* and not an aim (*other virtual-keyboards as I recall didn't have this issue, but tended to be smaller keyboards & I too liked `onboard` but note I've tested little without keyboard since team decided not to focus on it*).

Comment: Other keyboards are not as good. Is there any way to make LXQt force any window named "onboard" stay always on top no matter what? I remember that (back in the old days) Compiz had an option to force windows always on top.

Comment: @guiverc I found a solution :)

Comment: Well done....  I haven't explored no-physical-keyboard use since the team decided it was *wishlist* (*would love to have, but don't have time/resources to accomplish it*) and yeah I remember deciding I liked `onboard` the best.. I can't recall what settings I used (since *groovy* my tablet pc has been slow to boot *live* media making me less inclined to use it for QA testing etc)

Comment: Someone recently gave me an old  Surface RT because one cannot do anything in its locked down version of Windows. I have been doing a lot of [fun experiements](https://askubuntu.com/q/1429812/124466) with it.

Comment: Just a suggestion since Ubuntu is slow to boot on your tablet: The Raspberry Pi OS (both the ARM and the x86_64 versions) works lightning fast with old computers. I have been using it in my Surface RT all the time (Ubuntu GNOME is sluggish compared to that. Will try Lubuntu with LXQt sometime).

Comment: Nah; it's a non-standards-compliant firmware problem on some devices inc. my tablet that's at fault..  If I was to use another OS it'd be Debian (*the first & usually last OS I use on any day*) but software stack cannot get over what is a non-compliant firmware issue...  I'll have to re-test for https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1922342 (etc) again too now that I think of it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Onboard Settings and select "Window".
[image]
Uncheck "Dock to screen edge". Now, the "Force window on top" checkbox becomes active. Select it.

However, now onboard becomes a small window floating in the middle of the screen.
To fix it, move onboard to the bottom of the screen (or your preferred position), and resize the virtual keyboard size it appropriately.

### End results

[image]