# How to enable multitouch in Ubuntu 22.04 running on a tablet?

Tags: gnome, touchscreen, multi-touch

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 armhf version (for Raspberry Pi) in a [Surface RT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(2012_tablet)) ([*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429812/how-to-enable-multitouch-in-ubuntu-22-04-running-on-a-tablet#comment2490785_1429812)).
Is there any way to force Ubuntu use multitouch? Right now, Ubuntu seems to be considering multitouch events multiple mouse clicks (I can drag windows with one finger, though). If I touch with two fingers, the computer is confused, and the cursor is jumping between the two positions. I tried both X.Org and Wayland.

I also installed `xserver-xorg-input-multitouch`, but that did not help.

I don't know whether this is a driver issue (which cannot be fixed otherwise) or a configuration issue. How to debug whether multitouch events actually register in the system?

The Surface RT supports multitouch in Windows 8.1.

[image]

Comment: (*) [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206141/can-ubuntu-run-on-a-microsoft-surface-with-windows-rt) old question finally has an affirmative answer (although the performance of Raspberry Pi OS (LXDE) is much better than Ubuntu GNOME). I am using the Raspberry Pi image of Ubuntu. I will write a detailed answer with installation instructions soon.